# C++ access inner class in a template

Tags: c++

pls have a look at this code:

```
template<typename T>
class myclass {
private:

  class node {
    friend class myclass;

    T t;

    node(T t_) : t(t_) {};
  };

  node nd;

  node getNode();

public:
  myclass(T t_) : nd(node(t_)) {};

  T get() {
    auto node = getNode();
    return node.t;
  }

};

template<typename T>
myclass<T>::node myclass<T>::getNode() {
  return nd;
}
```

I define the method `getNode()` outside the template, and the compiler report this error:

`missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'myclass<T>::node'
myclass<T>::node myclass<T>::getNode() {`

how should I write it correctly?

Comment: just to add a bit to the given answer... when you write `myclass<T>::node` it might be that after that you will add a specialisation of `myclass`  where `node` is not a type but a member, hence compiler needs your help to be certain that `node` is a type, not something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to use `typename` keyword for dependent type `myclass<T>`

```
template<typename T>
typename  myclass<T>::node myclass<T>::getNode() {
~~~~~~~~
  return nd;
}
```

Comment: why I should add `typename`? Generally when I define member function outside the template class I don't have to add that....

Comment: @ZiqiLiu check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1870232) post to understand why.